# How to apply If condition for following result?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

`echo` of `$res` showing following result:-

`stdClass Object ( [permissionId] => 23 [roleId] => 14 [view] => 0 [add] => 0 [edit] => 0 [deleteRole] => 0 [status] => 1 [moduleId] => 1 )`

I have tried like something below

```
if($res->view = 1 or $res->add = 1 or $res->edit = 1 or $res->deleteRole = 1 ){ 
     echo "condition true";
} else {
     echo "condition false";
}
```

But it always echo condition true. Is if condition is right? Please help me how to write if condition.

Comment: use this 
if($res->view == 1 or $res->add == 1 or $res->edit == 1 or $res->deleteRole == 1 ){ 
     echo "condition true";
} else {
     echo "condition false";
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change to `==` Comparison Operator, if you put `=` it always true, the assignment operator always return true

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are not comparing, you are just doing assignment. `=` used for assignment not for comparison.

So use `==` instead of `=`

```
if($res->view == 1 or $res->add == 1 or $res->edit == 1 or $res->deleteRole == 1 ){ 
         echo "condition true";
    } else {
         echo "condition false";
    }
```

OR

```
if($res->view == 1 || $res->add == 1 || $res->edit == 1 || $res->deleteRole == 1 ){ 
     echo "condition true";
} else {
     echo "condition false";
}
```

Note:- Rest it's up-to-you what you want to compare and in which manner. So adjust code accordingly.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Give == (Comparison operator) rather than = (Assignment operator) and ||

```
if(($res->view == 1) || ($res->add == 1) || ($res->edit == 1) || ($res->deleteRole == 1) ){ 
     echo "condition true";
} else {
     echo "condition false";
}
```